# How to display and image from database outside the show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called Property and is no problem to display the image of a single property in the show page, i guess due to some rails magic:

```
<%= image_tag @property.image_url %>
```

This works fine.. However i want to display the image from another controller called pages_controller.rb in the index view, so i did:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @property_image = Property.first
end
```

In the pages/index view i can call any data this way but not the image

```
<%= @property_image.adress %>  #this works fine

<%= @property_image.image_url %>  #this is not working
```

Why is this happening??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're not putting it in a image tag, like you did in the first place.

```
<%= image_tag @property_image.image_url %>
```

Answer (score 0):

SORRY GUYS.. MY BAD.

I am working with carrierwave and the storage was set to :fog instead of :file.

Nothing to do with Active record..